# AS2 Server Software Costs

Tags: untagged

We're currently using Cleo LexiCom as our server software for receiving EDI transmissions via the AS2 protocol.  We have 7 trading partners per year, and this runs us about $800/year for support from Cleo.  We need to expand from 7 trading partners to 10 or so, and Cleo charges roughly $600 per new host, plus an expanded yearly support fee.

My question(s) are:

1. Does anyone know of a cheaper developer of AS2 server software, and perhaps one that doesn't charge per new host?
2. Does anyone have any clue why we are being charged an upfront fee for new hosts, and if this is a standard practice for AS2 software providers?  It seems really odd that we are required to pay upfront costs for this.  I could completely understand an increase in the yearly support, however.

Comment: Sorry, shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have been extremely happy with our CLEO/Lexicom (VLTrader) support for AS2/FTP communications. The cost are high, but because of our growth we planned ahead and bought new 'mailboxes' in packets of 5 or 25 vs 1 at a time. Still expensive, but cheaper in the long run.
Another benefit with VLTrader is that as we are moving from a Trading Partners Workgroup (Emanio) system to TIE Commerce, there is no need to swap out the VLTrader front end, so the switch is transparent to our customers.

Good luck!

Comment: Choose this answer.  If it were my company I'd go with an alternative, but it isn't worth it to implement a new AS2 server daemon.  The savings would be insignificant to us.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with OpenAS2 is that it is not DGI certified.  You will run into  partners that are unwilling accept communication from software that is not certified inter-operable.

The AS2 Connector http://www.rssbus.com/solutions/as2/ is easy to setup and administer and is FAR less expensive than the prices that you have quoted (even free for a single trading partner).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasonably priced AS2 servers out there. I have experience with two of them:

If you want something easy to set up an administer, you might want to check out Softshare ECS (http://www.softshare.com/software/ecs/ disclaimer: I work for Softshare) which doesn't charge per-partner.

There is also an open source Java AS2 server called OpenAS2 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/openas2/), which I have tested. The configuration can be a little complex, which may or may not matter to you, and I don't believe it has any translation capabilities, but it is free.

If you're not doing a high volume of EDI, you can also outsource the AS2 portion of your system to a Web EDI provider. Then your users can login to a Website (sort of like Webmail) and review transactions. On the other hand, if you're doing a lot of transactions, then keeping a system in place that can interface with your ERP package directly is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The UltraESB is a both a Free and Open Source Enterprise Service Bus, with AS2/EDI support. Its free for unlimited production use with any number of partners, and can perform message/protocol translations, notifications, monitoring etc as well. [Refer to the reference guide here](http://docs.adroitlogic.org/display/esb/AS2+Reference+Guide).

Comment: [Product recommendations are now off-topic on Stack Exchange sites.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)